# AWS Rekognition throws exception Unable to get image metadata from S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I try to use AWS recognition with Java SDK.
I have the code below but it throws exception:

```
    private static final EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider();

    public List<TextDetection> recognize(String bucket, String name) {
        var amazonRekognition = createAmazonRekognition();
        var detectTextRequest = new DetectTextRequest()
                .withImage(getImage(bucket, name));
        var detectTextResult = amazonRekognition.detectText(detectTextRequest);
        return detectTextResult.getTextDetections();
    }

    private AmazonRekognition createAmazonRekognition() {
        return AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER)
                .build();
    }

    private Image getImage(String bucket, String name) {
        return new Image()
                .withS3Object(new S3Object()
                        .withName(name)
                        .withBucket(bucket));
    }
```

I've create a new IAM with permissions *AmazonS3FullAccess* and *AmazonRekognitionFullAccess*.

When I run the execute method it throws:

```
Unable to get image metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue doing few things:

- I've added region `US_WEST_2` to `AmazonRekognition` instance
- S3 bucket was moved to `US_WEST_2` region

Answer (score 1):

AmazonRekognition and your S3 bucket should be in same region.

[supported region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#rekognition_region)